# ViM: Define syntax region in multiple buffers via bufdo

Tags: vim

If I execute the command `syn region Region1 matchgroup=Highlight1 start=+(+ end=+)+` individually on three different buffers, the syntax region Region1 is properly defined in all three buffers.

However if I execute it via bufdo, like `bufdo syn region Region1 matchgroup=Highlight1 start=+(+ end=+)+` the syntax region is missing on the last buffer.

I would like to define this region in all active buffers but I don't understand why bufdo is failing.  Could somebody help?

Thanks!